# File[] array to imageicon java

Tags: java, arrays, file, jfilechooser, imageicon

I am using a `JFilehooser` to load multiple images to a `File[]`.

I then want to load the `File[]` to multiple `ImageIcon`s. For example:

```
if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File[] files = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
    ImageIcon MyImage = new ImageIcon();
    MyImage = files[0];
}
```

Of course that code doesn't work, but that's what I want to do. How do I do it?

Comment: You have a problem to load the ImageIcon or to load ImageIcon**s** ? One can be answered [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html). The other can be answered with a loop

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to create array of `ImageIcon` for selected files:

```
ImageIcon[] imageIcon = Arrays.stream(files).map(file -> new ImageIcon(file.getAbsolutePath())).toArray(ImageIcon[]::new);
```